# which are the criteras to find out that the webserver can handle load using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan using 100 threads. how can we conclude that the web server can handle load? which are the factors we can be taken for the load test.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you need to define your own metrics for your test plan to get a load test pass.

Typical metrics I would use.

- Each response should come back in less than 250 ms. (Adjust to what your customer would expect)
- All responses should come back with a non error response.
- The server should be in a 'good state' after the load test. (Check memory, threads,database connection leaks etc)
- To many resources being consumed is also a bad sign. Database connections, memory , hard disk for log files. Define your own metrics here.

Successive 'soak tests' to compliment your load tests would also be a good idea.
Basically run the a smaller amount of jmeter tests every two hours (So the DBA's etc. don't complain) over the weekend and check on the Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you to first clarify your concepts about performance testing and its types (like load test, stress test, soak test etc). You can refer to following blog to get basic understanding about performance testing and its types:

[Load vs. Stress testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750509/load-vs-stress-testing)
http://www.testerlogic.com/performance-testing-types-concepts-issues/

Once you have a better understanding of concepts, you will be in better position to ask the right question. For now, you can focus on following points..

- what is expected load on your web server (in normal and extreme scenarios!)
- what is your acceptable criteria for response time, load time etc
- Once you know these numbers, you can create a jmeter test which runs for a specific time span (say 1 hour) and no. of threads increase step-by-step (100 user in first 10 minutes, 200 users from 10-20 mins, 300 users from 20-30 mins and so on). (hint: you can use ramp-up period to achieve this scenario).
- You can perform these tests and check the reports and compare the response time and other performance factors during first 10 minutes (when load was 100 users) and in last 10 minutes when load was maximum.

This is just to give you a high level idea. As i said before it will better if you first clarify basic performance testing concepts and then design/perform the actual testing.

Answer (score 0):

Like the [rjdkolb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338249/rjdkolb) said you have to define your metrics, check what you require from your service/app.

It all depends what service you are working with - do you have some stable load on the server, or some peaks, do you think there will be like 100 users online or 10000 at once, do you need fast answers or just proper answers in reasonable time. Maybe business foresee that the load will be building gradually through next year and it will start with just 100 requests per minute but will finish with 1000 per sec?

If you think that, like mentioned in other answer, you need an answer in less than 250 ms, then gradually increase load to check how many users/requests you can handle to still have responses on time. And maybe you need answers for 1000 users working simultaneously - then try load like this and check do they have they answers and how fast are they coming back? A lot to think about, do you think?

Try to read a bit about types of performance testing - maybe [here on soapui](http://www.soapui.org/Load-Testing/concept.html) or [this explanation of some metrics](http://loadstorm.com/load-testing-metrics/). A lot of texts on the internet can guide you in your way.

Have fun.